# Trying to remove a role with a command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a command that removes the role when they call the command. I am making it when the use of this command takes the unverified role away. I'm not getting any errors it just won't remove it at all. I've tried so many solutions but I just can not seem to get it.

> The role names match up, and the spelling is all correct

CODE:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_role('Unverfied')
async def verify(ctx , member : discord.Member):
        guild = ctx.guild
        verf = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Unverfied")
        await ctx.remove_roles(verf)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my issue, I needed to call the author part in the code.

```
await ctx.author.remove_roles(verf)
```